# I am totally new and I want to self-learn about nutrition and human health. Where should I start?

Tags: health-education

I am a 28 years old guy with no background about anything related to health science and its relevance. However, after 4 years of suffering depression, now I am quite keen to self-learn about exercise science related, such as nutrition, strength and condition training, anatomy, and a very basic foundation of health science. I am sorry if I mentioned these name wrong or inappropriate or overlapped, as I have no idea about this field's terminology. What I am trying to do now is to take the very first step, and I think about studying very basic of physiology, anatomy, biology and chemistry from Khanacademy. Am I correct with that thought? If not, please tell me what I should learn first. My goal is just to educate myself, not trying to be a doctor, it would be great if I can though. Thank you for your advice in advance guys.

Answer (score 2):

That's awesome you'd like to learn about exercise science!

Honestly where I'd recommend starting is getting a membership to a local gym and if you have a family, friend or co-worker that could act as your workout buddy that would be ideal.

Along with the actual doing -- to slowly start I'd recommend subscribing to a magazine or two (Men's Health, Muscle and Fitness etc..) something that will get your feet wet.

I was in your shoes right after high school -- 8 years, 3 degree's and too many certs later, I never would have believed it.  Once I started seeing results I became obsessed & have since entered the rehabilitation side as well.

Bottom line who knows where this will lead you -- just stick with it and don't overload your plate to start.

If you ever have any questions feel free to contact me -- I'd be happy to help you out!